# How to use the regex to parse the entire file and determine the matches were found , rather then reading each line by line?

Tags: python

Instead on reading each and every line cant we just search for the string in the file and replace it... i am trying but unable to get any idea how to do thth?

```
file = open(C:\\path.txt,"r+")
lines = file.readlines()
replaceDone=0
file.seek(0)
newString="set:: windows32\n"
for l in lines: 
     if (re.search("(address_num)",l,re.I) replaceDone==0:
        try:
            file.write(l.replace(l,newString))
            replaceDone=1
        except IOError:
             file.close()
```

Comment: i don;t need to use the  for l in lines  statement! as it reads the file line by line... if it is a huge file and the its goign to take  lot of memory

Comment: Well, something's going to have to read through the file somehow to find it - isn't it? :)

Comment: That’s not valid Python, and I don’t think that `replace` is necessary/doing what you think it does. Could you maybe explain what it is that needs doing in more detail, please?

Comment: @user2052617: You read the file line-by-line to *reduce* the memory usage.

Comment: Also note - that using `file.readlines()` is going to load it all into memory... Instead, you can directly iterate over the file...

Comment: Jon Clements: i want to use something like regex to search the string in the file directly  rather then reading  each and every line

Comment: minitech: basic   functionality is  search for a string in a  file ,after  we get the string we have a  id nos at the end of the string which need to be checked for corrretness if it is not then update the id no with the correct id (have another souorce wher we get the id no)

Comment: Rob:  that is i want to get the matching string with out reading all the lines in a file... (for a hude file there are many lines) i am looking for regex function which randomly searches  for the string i search in the line

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example you can adapt that replaces every sequence of '(address_num)' with 'set:: windows32' for a file:

```
import fileinput
import re

for line in fileinput.input('/home/jon/data.txt', inplace=True):
    print re.sub('address_num', 'set:: windows32', line, flags=re.I),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not very memory efficient but I guess it is what you are looking for:

```
import re
text = open(file_path, 'r').read()
open(file_path, 'w').write(re.sub(old_string, new_string, text))
```

Read the whole file, replace and write back the whole file.